# SQL Count Query with GroupBy

Tags: sql-server, select, pivot

I have data in table in the below format

```
ID CSLang VBLang Level Occurrence
1  FALSE  TRUE   1 - 4  1
2  FALSE  TRUE   5 - 9  1
3  FALSE  TRUE   0 - 0  1
4  TRUE   FALSE  1 - 4  1
5  TRUE   FALSE  5 - 9  1
6  TRUE   FALSE  10 - 15 1
7  TRUE   TRUE   0 - 0  1
8  FALSE  FALSE  0 - 0  1
```

I would like to get data as below (I want count of CSharp and VB which are true grouped by Level)

```
Level CountCS CountVB       
0 - 0   1       2       
1 - 4   1       1       
5 - 9   1       1       
10 - 15 1       0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like below (Assuming that you are using MySQL). See a demo fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08b00f/4

```
select level,
sum(CSharpLang = 'true') as CountCSharp,
sum(VBLang = 'true') as CountVBLang     
from table1
group by level
order by level
```

Per Update, if you are using `SQL Server` then you can do like below. A demo fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7fa05/3

```
select level,
sum(case when CSLang = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) as CountCSharp,
sum(case when VBLang = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) as CountVBLang     
from table1
group by level
order by level
```

Comment: your answer gave me the solution and when I used the following it worked

Comment: Select NumOfConditionalBPs, 
Sum(Case when ScriptEngine_7 = 'False' Then 1 else 0 End) as Script,
Sum(Case when ManagedOnlyEngine_5 = 'False' Then 1 else 0 End) as Managed
From DbgEngines
Group By NumOfConditionalBPs
Order By NumOfConditionalBPs

Comment: IF you run the fiddle links the solution appears to be correct. Why the down votes?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev, you got the syntax error cause you tried in SQLServer. There is bit difference in syntax. Check the edit now.